# atomic compare_exchange_weak having an atomic expected value

Tags: multithreading, c++11, atomic

I am trying to determine what the best way is to do a CAS with atomics in c++.
My example:

```
atomic<int> foo(0), bar(1);
while(!foo.compare_exchange_weak(bar, 2)) {}
```

gives error:

> no matching function for call to ‘std::atomic::compare_exchange_weak(std::atomic< int >&, int)

Essentially, what I want to do, is to have the old value of foo stored in bar, which is itself an atomic type. A solution to the above error is:

```
atomic<int> foo(0), bar;
int tmp = 1;
do
{
    bar = tmp;
}
while(!foo.compare_exchange_weak(tmp, 2));
```

Which respects the contract for compare_exchange_weak, and exits the loop only when bar has the value of foo at the moment that foo becomes is set to 2.

Yet, I am unsure if this is the best way to go about it. It seems to me that the first thing I wanted to do is the correct approach. Any comments on what is suitable, and if the second solution is OK?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this question has been up a while, but I had the same error today.

The first example is failing to compile because you are using an `atomic<int>` instead of just an `int` as an argument to `compare_exchange_weak`.  The following compiles and runs on my pc:

```
atomic<int> foo(0);
int bar(1);
while(!foo.compare_exchange_weak(bar, 2)) {}
```

I think in the example you provided, both loops are equivalent. The problem lies in the type of the argument, not in the logic.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer, as it conforms to the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange), however, the code you presented isn't equivalent. I specifically wanted bar to be atomic. I guess I'll have to use the second loop.